# How can set useState initial value if I want to set initial value product.minimun

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I want to set purchase initial valua as increase useState value .like-
const [increase, setIncrease] = useState(purchase.minimum);
how can It possible?

`const [purchase, setPurchase] = useState({});

const [increase, setIncrease] = useState(0);`

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if i understood what you meant but if your looking to change the value of increase each time the purchase changes you can try this using useEffect.

```html
    useEffect(() => {
        setIncrease(Number(purchase.minimum));
        
    }, [purchase])
    
    const [purchase, setPurchase] = useState({});
    const [increase, setIncrease] = useState(0);
```